# Parse JSON response with Symfony2 JMS Serializer Bundle to Class

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer, data-mapping

In Symfony2, I have an Address entity and an AddressList entity. AddressList entity makes a collection of Address entities. I have a JSON response that needs to map to AddressList entity.

The AddressList always return null when mapped using JMS Serializer like this:

```
$this->get('jms_serializer')->deserialize($json, 'Foo\Bar\AddressList', 'json');
```

Now I know that if I add a key (addresses) at root level to JSON response then it works fine as it can map to that key in response object i.e.

```
{"addresses":[{...},{...}]}
```

But I want it to work with orphan array of objects as given below.

Thank you!

JSON response:

```
[{
  "property": "foo",
  "street": "bar",
  "town": "baz",
  "postcode": "123120"
},{
  "property": "baz",
  "street": "foo",
  "town": "bar",
  "postcode": "987654"
}]
```

Here is the Address entity:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar;
class Address
{
    public $property;
    public $street;
    public $town;
    public $postcode;
    ...
    // Getters Setters
}
```

Here is the AddressList entity that makes a collection of above Address entity.

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Type;
class AddressList
{
    /**
     * @Type("array<Foo\Bar\Address>")
     */
    public $addresses;
    ...
    // Getters Setters
}
```

Comment: I dont think your require response [{...},{...}] is valid JSON

Comment: Did you find an answer to that? If yes it would be great if you post it :-)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I had to amend the JSON response as I mentioned in my question. It might have a fix in recent updates but I have not tried it yet. If I come across any solution then I will post an update here.